# Open a website in new tab when clicking on Chrome App icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome App/Extension.

Technically, it's a Chrome App, since only apps have access to [Chrome USB API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb), and I need that. However, in reality, it works more like a Chrome Extension, since I allow specific websites to send messages through [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), and the app has no window for itself and runs in a background page.

Now I have an "App", that for all intents and purposes works as an extension. After install, however, an icon of this "non-App App" is installed in App launcher, where it does nothing and confuses the user. The nice solution would be to open a new website in a new Chrome tab after clicking on the icon that explains things.

However, I cannot find out if it's even possible. I can open a new "chrome-less" window and put the website there, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `chrome.browser.openTab({ url: "whatever"})`, with the `"browser"` permission. This is new in Chrome stable 42, so you might want to add `"minimum_chrome_version": "42"` to your manifest.

Comment: As a fallback, I think it's possible to do `window.open()` from the event script.

Comment: Better solution to the version problem is to add the permission, but still check if "chrome.browser" is defined; old chrome versions (39 tested) will still install the extension, and will just not open anything